# PyQt5 Calendar Widget Children

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I want to change the style of the calendar widget; however, I couldn't change the background of the months drop-down menu (which I guess is ComboBox).Also there are some dark gray rects at the sides of the 'Dec 2021' text. How could I change them, too? Thanks in advance.

Here is what I've done so far;

```
self.dateEdit.setStyleSheet(
        f"QDateEdit{{font-size: {int(settings['FONT_SIZE_PRIMARY']*0.6)}px; font-family: {settings['FONT']};\
    color: {settings['COLOR_PRIMARY']};background-color: {settings['COLOR_BG_PRIMARY']};}}"
        f"QCalendarWidget{{font-size: {int(settings['FONT_SIZE_SECONDARY']*0.7)}px;\
        font-family: {settings['FONT']};}}"
        f"QAbstractItemView{{background-color: {settings['COLOR_PRIMARY']};}}"
    )
```

[image: CalendarWidget]

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us what you've done so far to get to that point.

Comment: Oh sorry. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The month selection popup is actually a QMenu, so you need to use the appropriate selector.

The navigation bar has a hardcoded object name (`qt_calendar_navigationbar`), so you can use the `#id` selector.

```css
QMenu {
    background: orange;
}
QMenu::item:selected {
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background: rgb(255, 168, 88)
}
```

All buttons in the navigation bar have object names (always have a look at the sources to check for those), so you can style them individually:

- `qt_calendar_prevmonth`
- `qt_calendar_nextmonth`
- `qt_calendar_monthbutton`
- `qt_calendar_yearbutton`
- `qt_calendar_yearedit`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any source to learn more about stylesheets? Like what is the components of widgets and how customizable they are. For example, this is the first time I see '#id selector'.

Comment: @Emek it's all in the [stylesheet documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html), the important part is the [selector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) that explains the different ways to set widget and component properties. Remember that QSS are based on CSS2.1 and they respect its syntax and almost all of its properties (with some exceptions); most importantly, properties used exclusively for CSS2 (and removed from CSS2.1) or CSS3 are **not** supported. Other Qt specific properties are also available (like gradients).

Comment: Got it! Thanks again.

Comment: @Emek where do you get these ID's of buttons from? Is there any documentation about the structure of QT obbjects/widgets?

Comment: @Scrz, unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation like that. I just try using Qt doc for C++ and hope it works for python binding as well.

Comment: @Scrz those object names are hardcoded in the Qt sources.